# SQL database link slow on first run

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database `A` which is connected to another database `B` via a database link.

When I execute a `select count(*) from VIEW` on Database `A` (where `VIEW` reads data from Database `B`) it takes ~60 seconds.

All subsequent runs take ~1 second.
After disconnecting and reconnecting with my sql developer, the select still takes  ~1 second.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the data of the tables on the view is probably cached on DB2's [SGA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/memory.htm#i10093) after you query the view. Disconnecting your Sql Developer won't matter since data is cached at instance level not on your client.
If instance B is restarted or data is aged out from [DB Buffer Cache](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/memory.htm#i10221) it'll probably go to disk again and start going slow.

Comment: Can I somehow disable the cache / invalidate the cache? This would help improving the query

Comment: Hm... when I execute the select statement on Database B itself, it always takes just a few seconds

Comment: @matthias If it's a test environment try alter system flush buffer_cache; (don't try this on a prod environment) on instance 2

Answer (score 0):

Oracle at first create execution plan for every query. may be your view is complex and creation of its execution plan takes more time at first execution.next times because its execution plan exist in shared pool it runs fast.